# Js: assign arrow function name to variable

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, factory, arrow-functions

I have an arrow function:

```js
() => 'a'
```

Can I name this function by one of my variable, such that:

```js
let func_name = 'a';

// expected output
// let a = () => 'a';
```

Comment: You mean `let a = () => a.name;`?

Comment: name `() => 'a'` to `a`, which I can call `a()`;

Comment: Do you mean ```let a = () => 'a';``` and then able to call it like ```a()```?

Comment: This sounds like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117127/use-dynamic-variable-names-in-javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible. Since everything, except for primitive types, is an object in JavaScript, you can do:

The not so right way, which is polluting the global or current namespace:

```js
function func(){
  // func is an object, see Functions on MDN
  let func_name = 'a';

  this[func_name] = () => func_name;


  // To call it
  console.log(
    this[func_name]()
  );
}

func();
```

```js
// func is an object, see Functions on MDN
let func_name = 'a';

// Object.freeze, so obj cannot be changed, similar to const
// Object.seal, the structure cannot be changed.
const obj = Object.freeze({
  [func_name]: () => func_name
})

obj[func_name] = "aaaaa"; // Throws an error in strict mode

// To call it
console.log(obj[func_name]());
```

Bear in mind that you can always reassign `obj[func_name]` to anything. Depending on the implementation, you can use `Object.seal` or `Object.freeze`

Comment: I'd advise against adding random values to `this`. In the current code, `this` is going to be `window`, so you're actually making all of these global. It makes it very likely that something will clash. Worse yet, if strict mode is enabled, this code will fail because `this` would be set to `undefined` and thus you'd get an error for trying to set a property on it.

Comment: @VLAZ, that's why I recommended another implementation; like `obj = { [func_name]: () => func_name }`.

Comment: @AdamAzad but why use `this` at all if it's not recommended even by you?